# Python custom log handler from fileconfig

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, amazon-sns

I have a working setup of python logging based on an ini file config.

I am trying to create a custom handler to send aws-sns notification upon logging to a specific logger

I was able to achieve this by setting up the loggers and handlers from code. Like this=> http://pantburk.info/?blog=77

But, If I try to take the approach of setting up logger from config file, it's not working. I guess Python logging module is trying to look for the custom handler inside python logging.handlers package. My custom class is in my application.

**My config file**:

```
[loggers]
 keys=root,sns

[handlers]
 keys=consoleHandler,snshandler

[logger_root]
 handlers=consoleHandler
 level=CRITICAL

[logger_sns]
 handlers=snshandler
 level=DEBUG
 propagate=0
 qualname=sns

[handler_snshandler]
 class=coco.loggers.sns_handler.SNSHandler
 formatter=simpleFormatter
 level=DEBUG

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
 datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
 format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s

[formatters]
 keys=simpleFormatter
```

**My custom handler class**: coco.loggers.sns_handler.SNSHandler

```
import logging
from coco.notifier.sns import SNS

class SNSHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SNSHandler, self).__init__()

    def emit(self, record):
        SNS().queue(message=record.getMessage())
```

I am setting up logger from config file like this:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('/path/to/conf')
```

I see this exception when I try to setup logger

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loggers'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -3):

Use an additional import statement to 
import logging.conf module